# Tap photo in flutter show it bigger

Tags: flutter

I am making an app  in flutter and i want to know how i can make the photo to show the photo bigger when the user click on it . Like when you tap on a photo on facebook and automatically it opens it in a new widget bigger , where you can zoom and whatever. What i should add to my code?

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 12),
    width: 80,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/fa/65/51fa6566059dc396bb0867336affe718.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
        color: Colors.red,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color:
                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1)
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
  ),
```

Comment: Have you looked at pub.dev? There are quite a few packages which can do the work for you. This one for example: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view

Comment: Check this answer, zoom a photo when you press and hold just like Instagram preview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623892/flutter-long-press-on-picture-to-get-zoomed-preview-like-instagram/62625820