# Display photo bigger when click on it flutter

Tags: flutter, photo

How i can make a photo in my app to be displayed bigger when you click it . For example when you searching for a photo on google and then when you click it , it's popping out bigger .

```
children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 12),
                                    width: 80,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: NetworkImage(
                                                "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d4/05/f9/d405f9671b3dd8e365dd97e50e801f86.jpg"),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                              blurRadius: 2,
                                              spreadRadius: 1)
                                        ],
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                  ),
```

Comment: You can take a look at this answer it have all the detailed code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623892/flutter-long-press-on-picture-to-get-zoomed-preview-like-instagram/62625820#62625820

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the widget called Hero (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

Otherwise, you could simply use a variable "_imgWidth" set to 80 by default and as you click on the image wrapped in a InkWell or a GestureDetector, call

```
setState({
  _imgWidth = _imgWidth == 80 ? 160 : 80;
})
```